How do you get the StringVar (not the text value, the StringVar itself) of an Entry?
I'm trying to get the StringVar object associated with an Entry widget, but I can't figure out how.
I found this question: get StringVar bound to Entry widget
but none of the answers work for me. Both entry["textvariable"] and entry.cget("textvariable") return the name of the StringVar and not the StringVar itself (although the answer with the second explains it properly, unlike the answer with the first which is NOT clear that it only returns the name. I've submitted an edit for the first that fixes this). You're supposed to be able to get the StringVar from its name using entry.getvar(name), but this is returning a str with the contents of the StringVar instead of the StringVar itself. I don't understand why this is happening, because the answer that explains this is marked as correct, and the person who asked the question seems to have wanted the StringVar itself. Did something get changed? If so, how would I get the StringVar now? I'm using Python 3.11.9 at the moment. I would also prefer a method that doesn't need the name of the StringVar, as an Entry without a StringVar explicitly set seems to have a StringVar without a name.
Here is some example code:
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

root = Tk()

stringVar = StringVar(root, "test") # obviously in the real program I wouldn't be able to access this without using the Entry
entry = Entry(root, textvariable=stringVar)
entry.pack()

name1 = entry["textvariable"]
name2 = entry.cget("textvariable")
print(name1 == name2) # True

shouldBeStringVar = entry.getvar(name1)

print(name1, type(name1)) # PY_VAR0 <class 'str'>
print(shouldBeStringVar, type(shouldBeStringVar)) # test <class 'str'>


Currently tkinter does not support finding the reference of the variable using the internal name.  You need to create a dictionary to store the internal name to variable mappings.

@acw1668 what about my solution below?

@DanyaK Actually your solution does not address OP question.

@acw1668 I think my solution covers most of the OP's question, although I am not sure about his last sentence.

Specifically for the last part, if you create an Entry and don't set a textvariable, it creates one implicitly. The problem is that it has no name. By this, I mean that using entry["textvariable"] or entry.cget("textvariable") returns an empty string. If it's not possible to get the StringVar in this case, then I could make your answer work, but I would prefer a different solution.

I think that if you did not set any variable to the Entry, it will just have no textvariable at all. It will not create it automatically. Why do you think it will create it implicitly, where did you get this information from?

I think you overcomplicate it. If you want to get text from Entry then use entry.get() without using StringVar.

if you really need to use StringVar then keep it in some list or dictionary - like data = {entry: variable) and use data[entry].get(). Or you can assign StringVar to other class like entry.variable = StringVar()

I think the problem is that tkinter is a wrapper on module tk created in language tcl which has own rules and tkinter tries to recreate them.

the main question is why do you need it? Maybe your real problem is different and maybe there is better solution for your real problem.

Sorry, I just assumed that Entry required a StringVar to work, so it would create one if it wasn't provided one. I was trying to add a listener to the contents of the Entry. I know there is validation, but it doesn't seem appropriate for my use case.

If you know the name of the variable, you can simply "create" a StringVar and set its parameter "name" to that name. This way you will simply get the variable you created earlier. So try this:
...
string_name = entry["textvariable"]
TheVarObjectYouNeed = var = tk.StringVar(name=string_name)
print(f"The var {var} has a type {type(var)}, just as you wanted")
print(f'And it has the value "{var.get()}"')
...

Note that this code actually creates a new StringVar object. But since I set it to an existing name, "TheVarObjectYouNeed" will actually refer to the same internal variable inside the underlying TCL interpreter (as correctly stated in the comment below), same TCL variable is used for your Entry widget.

This does create a new instance of StringVar which refers to the same internal variable inside the underlying TCL interpreter because id(stringVar)  (stringVar is the original instance in OP question) not the same as id(var).

@acw1668 yes, you are right about that. This is what you meant in the comment to the OP's question: you can't find the actual stringVar instance using this method?

I just tried this, and the StringVar I got has the correct contents, but it's not working for adding a listener to the entry contents. I'm using entryContents_trace_add("write", functionName), but it never gets run when writing to the entry. It only runs if I edit it directly. using set.

@Choosechee trace_add is working for me, maybe you made a mistake

I think you overcomplicate it.
If you want to get text from Entry then use entry.get() without using StringVar

If you really need StringVar object then you can assign it directly to Entry (or any other class)
entry.my_variable = stringVar

and later you can access it with entry.my_variable
stringVar = StringVar(root, "test")
entry = Entry(root, textvariable=stringVar)
entry.my_variable = stringVar   # <---
entry.pack()

Eventually you can create own class which will do it automatically

This isn't a bad idea, but what if you later change your textvariable to something else (which most likely won't happen, but can still be done)? In this case, you will also need to remember to change it to my_variable, which can be easily forgotten.

as for me you overcomplicate it. Setting new textvariable is very, very unusuall situation. So I wouldn't bother it. You can always create own class which create automatically StringVar, and add function to replace textvariable (and don't allow to assign it directly. But if you want to get text then use entry.get() without StringVar - and problem with textvariable will be resolved.  And if you really need StringVar then better describe (in question) why you need it because maybe there is better solution.

BTW: If you have to change textvariable then problably you have something wrong in code logic

You're right, I like to complicate things. I usually always try to think of all the things that could go wrong. And I know that such situation will likely not happen, but who knows. There could be a situation where you need to change textvariable. But I completely agree with your comment that you will never need an actual StringVar instance.

maybe you should try to create own class Entry, and hide dirrect access to textvariable, and add function set_textvariable which will automatically assign it to entry.my_variable. And maybe it is good (complicate) task for you ;) And when you create this class then you can put it as answer. Maybe it will be useful for other users.

I don't really see the point in writing a new class. As you said, and I agreed, there are really no circumstances under which you would need to get StringVar instance.
